# Case-insensitive wildcard search with Elasticsearch node client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, wildcard, case-insensitive

I'm using Elasticsearch version 7.17.0 with node client and am trying to execute a wildcard search like so:

```
const query: QueryDslQueryContainer = {
      wildcard: {
        'fieldName.wildcard': '*ing',
        case_insensitive: 'true',
      },
    }
```

I receive the error

```
ResponseError: parsing_exception: [parsing_exception] Reason: [wildcard] query doesn't support multiple fields, found [fieldName.wildcard] and [case_insensitive]
```

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) indicates that case-insensitive wildcard search was added in version 7.10.0.  Not sure how to get case-insensitive wildcard queries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you query is wrong.

Try like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "field_name": {
        "value": "VALUE",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like the correct format for Elasticsearch but not for the node client's QueryDslQueryContainer?

Comment: I can test here, how did you import the QueryDslQueryContainer?